# Cypress Faker date format

Tags: date, format, cypress, faker

I use Faker module to generate the fake future date. I would like to have close future random date.

```
//Generate date
const dateOfTravel = faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05').toLocaleDateString();


//Input date
cy.get("#date").type(`${dateOfTravel}`)
```

The page field requires string format of the date as "YYYY/MM/DD" but I get "YYYY-DD-MM"

How I can covert it to required date or I need the different func

Answer (score 6):

`faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05')` returns a Date object which you can convert to correct string format in a few ways.

Unfortunately `.toLocaleDateString()` does not work.

I recommend `.toISOString()` instead, but it returns the time portion as well so you have to slice the result.

This passes:

```js
const d = faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05').toISOString().slice(0,10)
expect(d).to.match(/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
```

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Strings have a built-in `.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), which allows you to easily swap out one expression for another.

```js
const dateOfTravel = 
  faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05').toLocaleDateString();
cy.get("#date").type(dateOfTravel.replaceAll('-', '/'));
```

Additionally, the `en-US` Locale automatically uses the backslash as the separator.

```js
const dateOfTravel = 
  faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05').toLocaleDateString('en-US');
cy.get("#date").type(dateOfTravel);
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I got YYYY-MM-DD. When I add en-SU I got dd/mm/yyyy that is close already. May I now convert it to format yyyy/mm/dd somehow?

Comment: No worries! It probably is just a weird locale date string thing, where whatever locale you're using defaults to `-` instead of `/`.

Comment: ok, I put 'en-CA' option to localeDateString and got yyyy-mm-dd so now I can use replace method. Thanks. Yes it is Canadian website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate date and replace it with format yyyy-mm-dd using option 'en-CA'
2. Use replace twice (replaceAll returns error) to replace - on /

```js
const dateOfTravel = faker.date.between('now', '2024/05/05').toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
cy.get("#date").type(`${dateOfTravel.replace('-','/').replace('-','/')}`);
```